# Why is command prompt returning a gdal not found error

Tags: django, gdal, geodjango

I am trying to add geodjango to an already existing django project. I have installed everything that is request e.g postgressql proj geos e.t.c. I can't seem to install gdal on my system though. Everytime I try to run the project in local host it throws back a gdal not found error. I have tried using Osgeo4w, the .whl and the .msi file to try and install gdal. Can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Windos, the easiest way I've found is:

1. Install Gdal from whl, for examle: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/][1], if this link unavailable, the whl you need is not so difficult to find.
2. Add to `settings.py` this code(change name of virtual env if need):

   ````
      OSGEO_VENV = Path(__file__).parents[1] / 'venv/Lib/site-packages/osgeo/'
      GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = str(OSGEO_VENV / 'geos_c.dll')
      GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = str(OSGEO_VENV / 'gdal204.dll')
      os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + str(OSGEO_VENV)```
   ````